# How to mimic one page layout when user scroll down the page and display a animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I saw this website http://g1.gigabyte.com/about/

When you scroll down the page, it will show a animation,

I wonder how to show the animation smoothly,

I know it contains quite a lot of details.

So please give me some rough direction, thanks.

Comment: First of all, your question is a little undetailed - maybe you can add a little more details. What you see there is the now very often used parallax effect. There are tons of libraries for that, as mentioned by Kris. I can't really give an answer that follows the rules for answering without more details here.

Comment: Are you asking how to show the animation on scrolling to a particular height in the page or how to perform a particular animation??? Former is done by scroll events

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of tools and jQuery plugins that you can use to do this. [Google](http://google.com/?q=jQuery%20single%20page%20layout)

The best place to start is to open your browser's Developer Tools (F12) and start looking through the source.

Answer (score 1):

[Skroller](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) is a good library for doing work like this.  Another is [Superscroll](http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/).  Basically you attach to the onscroll event in the window, and perform actions based on the current scroll position.  One of the best examples of using the scroll to animate is the [Flat vs Realism](http://www.flatvsrealism.com/) site, learn the code from that and you will be a scroll animation master.